# How to assert today's date or older in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-dayjs

I am trying to write a function in Cypress, where it loops through all the columns for my start date (#EventStart) and makes sure that the start dates are today's current date or older. So for instance, I need this test to make sure that it is confirming that all the dates listed are either today's date (April 4) or earlier (April 3, 2, 1, etc, etc). So far I can get it to confirm today's date, but how can I add to the function so that it also looks for the days prior to today? Also, the way it is written, it is getting me GMT Time, how can I get it to display CST?

EDIT: This is how the date displays:   April 4, 2022, 1:00pm

```js
  public assertOldDate () {
    cy.get("#EventStart).each((el) => {
     let oldDate = new Date();
      oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate())
      cy.get("el").should("equal", oldDate);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The result would depend on the text format in the columns, can you give a sample of what it looks like please.

Comment: @TesterDick I just added it to the paragraph.

Comment: **A)** To check for "equal or lesser than", please consider if something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62079326/13658816) will work in your case. **B)** _it is getting me GMT Time, how can I get it to display CST_ --> to address this, please explore if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361866/13658816) and it's answers are helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) to parse the element text,

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

const today = dayjs()

cy.get('[id*="EventStart"]')
  .each($eventStart => {

    const dateText = $eventStart.text()

    Cypress.log({message: `Testing ${dateText}`})               // log as per web page
    const formatted = dateText.split(', ').slice(0,2).join(' ') // remove commas & time 
    const date = dayjs(formatted, 'MMMM DD YYYY')               // parse the text

    expect(date <= today).to.eq(true)
  })
```

Note, changed id selector to `[id*="EventStart"]` as id's are expected to bu unique. Using `#EventStart` seems to block the iteration.